# Backbone.marionette: jQuery document.ready not running on route

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

So I have a web application that routes from the login button to a dashboard where I run an `initialize()` function, which contains a `document.ready()` block. The problem is, that on the backbone `route` it seems like the `document.ready()` block isn't being run. Here some code to clearify:

Here's an event from my landing page view:

```
events:
    'click .pure-menu .signin': 
      () ->
        application.router.navigate('dash', {trigger: true})
```

That then routes the application to my dashboard view:

```
module.exports = class DashView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    id: 'dash-view'
    template: template

    initialize: ->

        $ ->
            $(".gridster ul").gridster(
                widget_margins: [10, 10]
                widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
            )
```

Where I have a jQuery `document.ready()` block with some code to be run once the dom is loaded.

I'm using the [Gridster](http://gridster.net/) library, but when the page routes this code does not get run, because the Gridster grids don't get initialized.

When I refresh the page every thing works as expected.

My guess it that when the page routes, jQuery doesn't get the "dom loaded" event, so therefore the block doesn't get executed? I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

And to solve using a hack, does anyone know how to route in backbone with a page refresh?

Comment: What adds `.gridster ul` to the DOM?

Comment: They're currently added as an unordered list in the template, and then the gridster library initializes them in my `initialize` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add your code in the `onDomRefresh` method instead of `initialize`.

Initialize is called as soon as the view is created and so the view's element is not placed in the DOM at that time, while onDomRefresh gets triggered after the view has been rendered, has been shown in the DOM or has been re-rendered, so it may suit better your needs.

You can check it out in the docs: [Marionette's view](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md)